# Is `f().a[0]` an xvalue?

Tags: c++

```
struct S{
    int a[3] = {1,2,3};
};

S&& f(){return S();}

&f().a;       //[Error] taking address of xvalue (rvalue reference)
&f().a[0];    //ok in GCC 5.1.0 and Clang 3.6.0

S s;
&static_cast<S&&>(s).a;     //[Error] taking address of xvalue (rvalue reference)
&static_cast<S&&>(s).a[0];  //ok in GCC 5.1.0 and Clang 3.6.0
```

> 5.7 An expression is an xvalue if it is:
>
> **(7.1) — the result of calling a function, whether implicitly or explicitly, whose return type is an rvalue reference to object type,**
>
> (7.2) — a cast to an rvalue reference to object type,
>
> **(7.3) — a class member access expression designating a non-static data member of non-reference type in which the object expression is an xvalue, or**
>
> (7.4) — a .* pointer-to-member expression in which the first operand is an xvalue and the second operand is a pointer to data member.
>
> 5.2.1 Subscripting
>    A postfix expression followed by an expression in square brackets is a postfix expression. One of the expressions
>   shall have the type “array of `T`” or “pointer to `T`” and the other shall have unscoped enumeration
>   or integral type. The result is of type “`T`”. The type “`T`” shall be a completely-defined object type. The expression `E1[E2]` is identical (by definition) to `*((E1)+(E2))<<*t` [ Note: see 5.3 and 5.7 for details of `*` and
>   `+` and 8.3.4 for details of arrays. —end note ], **except that in the case of an array operand, the result is an lvalue if that operand is an lvalue and an xvalue otherwise.**

So, is `f().a[0]` an xvalue?

I think `f().a[0]` should be an xvalue.

---

[Edit1]

Ignoring `&f().a;` and `&f().a[0];` because  12.2[class.temporary]p5.2

> The lifetime of a temporary bound to the returned value in a function return statement (6.6.3) is not
>   extended; the temporary is destroyed at the end of the full-expression in the return statement

`static_cast<S&&>(s).a` is an xvalue(7.2 and 7.3).

" ***except that in the case of an array operand, the result is an lvalue if that operand is an lvalue and an xvalue otherwise.***"

So I think `static_cast<S&&>(s).a[0]` should be an xvalue, but

`&static_cast<S&&>(s).a[0];  //ok in GCC 5.1.0 and Clang 3.6.0`

Questing:

Am I wrong? If I am wrong, show me an example that subscripting an array results an xvalue.

Comment: Your code contains UB, it's better to rewrite `f()` as `S f() {...}` (the question is still valid though).

Comment: This is [CWG 1213](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1213)

Comment: @AntonSavin It's not UB. It's the same as returning a reference to `const`. The lifetime of the temporary is extended to the lifetime of the reference, which is the full expression in which `f()` appears.

Comment: @0x499602D2 [class.temporary]p5.2 *"The lifetime of a temporary bound to the returned value in a function return statement (6.6.3) is not
extended"*

Comment: @dyp Oh goodness! Sorry I just woke up! :)

Comment: @AntonSavin: That would cause the first bolded bullet point to no longer apply.  Better: `T&& f(T&& t) { return t;}  &f(T()).a; &f(T()).a[0];`

Comment: @BenVoigt  `T&& f(T&& t) { return t;} //[Error] cannot bind 'T' lvalue to 'T&&'`

Comment: @stackcpp OK you need std::move thrown in. In fact you could just use std::move in place of f(). Important thing is that the return value is an rvalue reference to a temporary that isn't dead yet.

Comment: As far as I can tell, neither clang++ nor g++ implement CWG1213. I couldn't find any bug reports mentioning 1213 either, so why don't you file a bug report for both?

Comment: @dyp I am not sure if it is a bug.

Comment: @dyp it seems like this is still not implemented, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33161003/1708801) I was pretty confused when I read N4140 until I found the defect report. xvalues are not covered very well anywhere :-(

Comment: @dyp well [clangs defect report support](http://clang.llvm.org/cxx_dr_status.html) has 1213 listed as unknown. A bug report seems reasonable.

Comment: @dyp filed a [bug report](https://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=25357)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell you are indeed correct, this looks a *"bug"*, although to be fair this changed recently with [CWG defect 1213](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1213) which says:

> Because the subscripting operation is defined as indirection through a pointer value, the result of a subscript operator applied to an xvalue array is an lvalue, not an xvalue. This could be surprising to some.

and this changed section 5.2.1 [expr.sub] as follows:

> A postfix expression followed by an expression in square brackets is a
>   postfix expression. One of the expressions shall have the type
>   **“array of T” or** “pointer to T” and the other shall have unscoped enumeration or integral type. The result is <s>an lvalue</s> of type
>   “T.” The type “T” shall be a completely-defined object type.62 The
>   expression E1[E2] is identical (by definition) to *((E1)+(E2)) [Note:
>   see 5.3 [expr.unary] and 5.7 [expr.add] for details of * and + and
>   8.3.4 [dcl.array] for details of arrays. —end note]**, except that in the case of an array operand, the result is an lvalue if that operand
>   is an lvalue and an xvalue otherwise.**

So indeed the result of `f().a[0];` and `static_cast<S&&>(s).a[0]` should be xvalues.

This defect did not have a proposed resolution until December 2012 and [clangs defect report support](http://clang.llvm.org/cxx_dr_status.html) lists the support of that defect report as unknown so most likely the implementers have not gotten to fixing this defect yet.

**Update**

Filed a clang [bug report: Subscript operator applied to an temporary array results in an lvalue](https://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=25357).

Answer (score 0):

I could test in Clang 3.4.1 std=c++11.

Here are my conclusions :

`int i = f().a[0]` would be correct : you get a reference to a temporary struct, the lifetime of the temporary is extended for the duration of the reference, you take a **value** : fine.

`int *i = &f().a[0]` is accepted by the compiler. However, the warning on `f` saying that you are *returning reference to local temporary object* makes sense here. The lifetime of the temporary object is extended for the duration of the reference : here the time to copy the address. As soon as you have taken the address of `a`, the containing object vanishes and you only have a *dangling reference*.

`int *i = f().a` is exactly same case as previous one.

But when you do  `&f().a`, you are taking *the address of an rvalue of type 'int [3]'*, and it does not make sense to take such an address : you can only take its value.

Let's go one step further :

`S s = f();` is correct. You get a reference to a temporary struct, the lifetime of the temporary is extended for the duration of the reference, you take a **value** : fine.

Now `&s.a[0]` is a well defined pointer to `int`, as is `int *ix2 = &static_cast<S&&>(s).a[0];`

You can even write : `int (*ix3)[3] = &s.a;` to take the address of an array to 3 `int`, but still for same reason, you cannot write `&static_cast<S&&>(s).a` because you would take *the address of an rvalue of type 'int [3]'*

TL/DR

With `S s = f();` `s.a` is a well defined rvalue, `s.a[0]` is a well defined lvalue (you can write `s.a[0] = 5;`).

`f().s` is a rvalue, but using it will invoke UB, because it ends in a reference to a temporary object that will be destroyed before you can use it.

`f().s[0]` can be used as a well defined rvalue. You can use it as a lvalue, but for the same reason as above, it would invoke UB.