# Using a temporary array as an lvalue

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer, c++14

This program is ill-formed:

```
struct X { int i; };

int main() {
    (X { }).i = 1;
}
```

`i`, a sub-object of the temporary `X { }`, cannot be used as an lvalue because  `X { }` is an rvalue.

However, this silently compiles with GCC 5.2.1 and `-Wall`:

```
using Y = int[10];

int main() {
    (Y { })[0] = 1;
}
```

If the compiler is correct, then this time, the zeroth element of `(Y { })`, which is a subobject of `(Y { })`, can be treated as an lvalue.

My questions are:

1. Is the second program ill-formed?
2. Why (not), even though both programs seem to treat a subobject of a temporary as an lvalue?

Comment: Clang bug was [resolved in 4.0](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=25357)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe the second case is ill-formed, if I am reading [defect report 1213](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1213) correctly, it says:

> Because the subscripting operation is defined as indirection through a
>   pointer value, the result of a subscript operator applied to an xvalue
>   array is an lvalue, not an xvalue. This could be surprising to some.

and the resolution was the following changes to the draft C++ standard section 5.2.1 [expr.sub], (*bolded sections were added and strikethroughs were removed*):

> A postfix expression followed by an expression in square brackets is a
>   postfix expression. One of the expressions shall have the type
>   **“array of T” or** “pointer to T” and the other shall have unscoped enumeration or integral type. The result is <s>an lvalue</s> of type
>   “T.” The type “T” shall be a completely-defined object type.62 The
>   expression E1[E2] is identical (by definition) to *((E1)+(E2)) [Note:
>   see 5.3 [expr.unary] and 5.7 [expr.add] for details of * and + and
>   8.3.4 [dcl.array] for details of arrays. —end note]**, except that in the case of an array operand, the result is an lvalue if that operand
>   is an lvalue and an xvalue otherwise.**

The result of `Y{}` is a prvalue from section `5.2.3` *[expr.type.conv]*:

> Similarly, a simple-type-specifier or typename-specifier followed by a
>   braced-init-list creates a temporary object of the specified type
>   direct-list-initialized (8.5.4) with the specified braced-init-list,
>   and its value is
>   **that temporary object as a prvalue.**

So the result of `(Y { })[0]` should be an xvalue and therefore ill-formed since assignment requires a modifiable lvalue on the left operand:

> The assignment operator (=) and the compound assignment operators all group right-to-left. All require a
>   modifiable lvalue as their left operand [...]

We can find the updated wording from the defect report in the  [draft C++14 standard](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/blob/master/papers/n4140.pdf), so this change was applied after C++11 but may apply to C++11 since this was a applied via a defect report.

Why section `5.3.1` *[expr.unary.op]* was not also updated is unclear to me, it seems somewhat inconsistent to say the result is an *lvalue* which it is not in all cases.

**Update**

Filed a [clang bug report](https://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=25357).

Comment: Can you explain why xvalues are not modifiable in this scenario?

Answer (score 4):

The draft of C++ standard (N4527) § 5.2.1 clause 1 says:

> The expression E1[E2] is identical (by definition) to *((E1)+(E2))

§ 5.3.1 clause 1 says:

> The unary * operator performs indirection: the expression to which it is applied shall be a pointer to an object type, or a pointer to a function type and **the result is an lvalue** referring to the object or function to which the expression points.

Comment: Seems to be an inconsistency in the language.