# Should the member access operator of an rvalue be an xvalue?

Tags: c++, decltype, rvalue, lvalue, xvalue

In the [cpprefernce section: Value categories](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category), it states that "the member of object expression, where a is an rvalue and m is a non-static data member of non-reference type" is an xvalue.  In the standard (I found in: [N4140, the draft C++14 standard](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/draft.pdf)) it states (on page 87) that "An expression is an xvalue if it is... a class member access expression designating a non-static data member of non-reference type in which the object expression is an xvalue."

I wanted to check my understanding of this with the following code:

```
struct B { // B for Boring...
  int i{0};
};

template <typename T> struct V {
  V() { cout << "V" << endl; }
};

template <typename T> struct V<T &> { // Partial Specialization
  V() { cout << "V&" << endl; }
};

template <typename T> struct V<T &&> { // Partial Specialization
  V() { cout << "V&&" << endl; }
};

int main() {
  int i{1};
  V<decltype((1))> v1;       // V
  V<decltype((i))> v2;       // V&
  V<decltype((move(i)))> v3; // V&&

  V<decltype((B().i))> v4;       // V, why not V&&?
  V<decltype((move(B()).i))> v5; // V&& as expected
}
```

If my calculations are correct, then `B().i` is a "member of object expression, where [`B()`] is an rvalue," and according to the reference that expression should be an xvalue, and the type returned by `decltype` should be int&&.  Note that I'm using `gcc version 7.3.0 (Ubuntu 7.3.0-27ubuntu1~18.04)`, and I tried it with no flags and with `-std=c++14`.

(To be clear, I'm also checking my understanding of "decltype" here, but the standard I previously linked to and the reference agree verbatim and quite clearly on the behavior of decltype).

Sorry, that wasn't a question...  Am I right?  Should the reference be updated to clarify this behavior?

Comment: This seem to be a (fixed) bug in gcc, [clang](https://wandbox.org/permlink/iA6aMIex6mbcHvyj), as well as [newer gcc](https://wandbox.org/permlink/ZB9xe1kEjSixXTwv) print `V&&` as expected

Comment: The text you quote from N4140 doesn't apply to `v4`, since the object expression `B()` is a prvalue, not an xvalue.  And notes are non-normative anyway.  The actual rule is in [expr.ref]/4.2 "If `E1` is an lvalue then `E1.E2` is an lvalue; otherwise `E1.E2` is an xvalue."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are correct this is a bug, this looks similar to [Is `f().a[0]` an xvalue?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31206988/1708801) but this case dealt speifically with arrays which had a carve out in [[expr.sub]p1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/expr.sub#1) which said the result was an lvalue but [deemed a defect](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1213). Otherwise the same logic applies.

We can see it was [fixed in clang 4.0](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=25357) and if we check [clang < 4.0 live](https://wandbox.org/permlink/V16qDIL03ETMZCbN), we obtain the same non-conforming results you see from [gcc less than the most HEAD](https://wandbox.org/permlink/oxCguY1Ncl36VLyh) but [clang 4.0 and > live](https://wandbox.org/permlink/XBHxPm9N7yT5Djaj) this is also fixed.

Also note the problem from the [Is `f().a[0]` an xvalue?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31206988/1708801) is also only fixed in [gcc HEAD](https://wandbox.org/permlink/WRbOwxUUDEZ38kWD).

Also note that [[expr.ref]p4.2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/expr.ref#4.2)

> ... If E1 is an lvalue, then E1.E2 is an lvalue; if E1 is an xvalue, then E1.E2 is an xvalue; otherwise, it is a prvalue...

changed after C++11 to [this](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.ref#4.2.sentence-2):

> ... If E1 is an lvalue, then E1.E2 is an lvalue; otherwise E1.E2 is an xvalue. ...

It looks like the change was originally part of [DR 616](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3714.html#616) although what it has to do with [indeterminate values](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23415661/1708801) I am not sure.

Comment: Thanks.  In case it matters to anyone, I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.1 and after upgrading gcc using apt it gives the same (incorrect) behavior.  I'll also mention that I was using an older standard, because I'm trying to get "up to speed" with c++14 before moving to c++17, but in a newer standard (which I just looked up) there is significantly different language due to the introduction of "Temporary Materialization."  (See page 88 of http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2017/n4659.pdf).